# AdSense on NextJS and Vercel project says Ads.txt not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, adsense

It's been a couple of weeks since I started integrating AdSense on my NextJS and Vercel project, however AdSense keeps saying "Ads.txt not found" along with "Earnings at risk - You need to fix some ads.txt file issues to avoid severe impact to your revenue.".

The approval status on my website on AdSense is "Ready".

When I visit non www website, I'm redirected to www website and the ads.txt shows correctly.
When I visit HTTP version of the website, I'm redirected to HTTPS and the ads.txt shows correctly.

Eg when I visit http://mywebsite.com/ads.txt, I'm redirected to https://www.mywebsite.com/ads.txt and the ads.txt shows correctly.

The ads.txt file is placed into `/public/ads.txt` in the project structure.

The https://www.mywebsite.com/ads.txt is indexed on Google. I've checked this on Google Search Console.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

I would expect the error message to disappear.

Comment: Hello @AdiSaktiJrs, I've renamed the file to "ads.txt" instead of "Ads.txt" and also ensured the file can be accessed on the non-www website without redirects. I also had to set-up my AdSense entity to mywebsite.com instead if www.mywebsite.com and then the ads started working. It's more of a workaround than a fix.